# Requests to stripe webhook next.js endpoint hosted on vercel rejected

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, vercel

I have a next.js project which received events from stripe via an api route, see code below.

This works perfectly locally using the Stripe CLI receiving events.

However when i deployed my application to vercel, i get the following error when events are sent from stripe:

```
lambda 400 POST /api/stripe/webhooks ... INFO ❌ Error message: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing END
```

**Webhook code** (in next.js api route):

```
...
// Stripe requires the raw body to construct the event.
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ['POST', 'HEAD'],
})

const webhookHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {

    const buf = await buffer(req)
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']!

    let event: Stripe.Event

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret)
    } catch (err) {
      // On error, log and return the error message.
      console.log(`❌ Error message: ${err.message}`)
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
      return
    }
...
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: will vercel by default enable some middleware which modifies the request body?

Comment: @wsw i think so, but i cant figure out how to retrieve the raw body to then supply to stripe.

Answer (score 1):

After numerous hours of reading about different potential causes, it turned out to be a rogue whitespace & newline in my Vercel project environment variable value.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.